# Jquery dialog with fadeIn/fadeOut and load issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog

My client wants a fadeIn/fadeOut image when loading interior pages. This is the page in question: http://angelynngrant.com/mei3/ouragency.html

Problems:
(1) fadeIn does not work;
(2) fadeOut works, but leaves a ghosted rectangle before 'destroy';
and (3) often onload (and on refresh), the modal appears in the top left of corner of the window and then "hops" in place to fadeOut.

I've adjusted my css to make most elements of the dialog box disappear and/or be transparent (e.g. .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {visibility:hidden; background:transparent;}).

I have the load in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
    $(window).load(function() {                         
        $("#ModalSlide7").dialog({
            width: 564,
            height: 808,
            modal: true
        }); 
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide(); 
    });
</script>
```

And I have the rest of the modal in the body:

```
<div id="ModalSlide7">
    <img id="slide7" src="images/7.jpg" alt="Game of Authors vintage game">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#slide7').fadeIn(3000, function() {
            $('#slide7').fadeOut(3000).queue(function (next) {
                $('#ModalSlide7').dialog('destroy').remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(Note: Site design/styling is not finished.)

Comment: I don't have much time to look into this, but two thoughts to think about. First is maybe FadeIn doesn't do anything because the image is already 100% opacity. Not sure if it needs to start at 0 or if fadeIn will make it start at 0. Second is that I think dialog moves the html elements around the page when it pops-up. Since you open it on window load I bet that fadeIn already started and gets cut short when dialog moves the elements around the page. Maybe you can start the fadeIn on the open event of the dialog and hide the img with css to start with.

Comment: here is the open event: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FQ6Q2/20/) I put together of what I think you are after. Hope this helps!

```
$(function () {

    // On document ready setup your dialog to define what happens
    // when it gets shown and hidden and some basic settings
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        show: {
            effect: 'fade',
            duration: 2000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: 'fade',
            duration: 2000
        },
        open: function(){
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        close: function(){
            $(this).dialog('destroy');
        }
    });

    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").remove();

    // Finally open the dialog! The open function above will run once
    // the dialog has opened. It runs the close function! After it has
    // faded out the dialog is destroyed
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

I think your confusion comes with mixing functions provided by the jquery ui dialog and general jQuery functions (e.g. you were using `fadeIn` as opposed to configuring the dialog to fade in when the `show` function is called). [Here is a big list](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) of all the functions and lots of examples!

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help. It works, although not graying out the rest of the page while the fadeIn/fadeOut/destroy happens. Still, I'm not sure my client needs the graying out. In fact, I'm going to try to dissuade her from these pop up effects. I'm thinking it might be very annoying on repeated viewings. I'm torn between client's vision and good design.